# Why are my Betta’s fins curled and maybe spotted?

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, betta

I bought a Betta for my daughter that has quickly become my 5th child. We bought him from Petsmart, as I knew little about where else to go - especially with Covid19. He is in a 3.5 gallon (13 liters) tank with a filter that was advertised specifically for Betta fish. I conditioned the water and added a heater.

When we brought him home, his fins were curled up though they seem to be releasing a little more now but not fully. He seems to dart around a bit and then hid behind his filter though he will come out once and a while and be playful. Its been 5 days and I’m worried he might have issues with his fins and if there is something more I should be doing. His fins have a few black spots on them. I will get a water test kit tomorrow to ensure we have the levels right. Just wondering what you guys think. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look around, there are several [questions about bettas](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbetta%5d%20is%3aquestion) that might help you. For example: [Bettas with black dots on fins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18829/12501) and [Why did my betta’s fins grow back curly?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/24282/12501).

Comment: Did you cycle the tank before putting the beta in it? If not, it's likely suffering from ammonia poisoning.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong with the fins of your betta. There is that darker spot on its forehead that might indicate a problem, but even that is within normality.

If you notice a change of behavior, then you could go to the vet to have a look.

Comment: Really? Glad to hear it. Do juveniles often have curled ventricle fins?

Comment: As I said, all fins look beautiful. There might be some deformation of the pectoral fin, but it might be also an illusion - the angle in the photo is not suitable for good evaluation. BTW, *"ventricle"* and *"ventral"* are different words :)